# How to install wxpython 4 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, python, wxpython

I am trying to install the wxPython 4 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

```
sudo pip install wxpython
```

I get this warning first

```
    The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

and eventually error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-SyaTU1/wxpython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-bzIjlK/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-SyaTU1/wxpython/
```

I had similar problem with wxPython3 and the solution was to install it with get

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk-3.0
```

I also was able to install wxPython 4 for Python 3 but not for Python 2.7 ([instructions](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/05/05/how-to-install-python-3-wxpython-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-easy-guide/))

Also, I am very confused why it takes so much CPU to install wxpython

```
sudo pip install wxpython
```

[image: see this image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After waiting long enough the process was complete and I got wxPython 4 installed.

- run

  ```
  sudo apt install make gcc libgtk-3-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev python-gst-1.0 python3-gst-1.0 libglib2.0-dev ubuntu-restricted-extras libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
  ```
- `sudo pip install wxpython` or `sudo pip3 install wxpython`
- wait for a while for it to install

after completion, you will see this message.

```
The directory '/home/user-ii-6/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

The directory '/home/user-ii-6/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting wxpython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/31/bd55ab40e406a026a7fda0bb5eb61f466682544ae91ac26267c750f5e618/wxPython-4.0.3.tar.gz (68.5MB)
    100% |\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588| 68.5MB 929kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxpython) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyPubSub in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxpython) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from PyPubSub->wxpython) (3.6.6)
Installing collected packages: wxpython
  Running setup.py install for wxpython ... done
Successfully installed wxpython-4.0.3
```

Comment: For 20.04 the dependencies that worked were `sudo apt install make gcc libgtk-3-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev  python3-gst-1.0 libglib2.0-dev ubuntu-restricted-extras libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`

Answer (score 3):

Since there are various options for distro and wx port (GTK2 or GTK3) then the files can not all be located in the same folder for easy access by pip. This simply just means that you'll need to drill down a little further to find the URL to give to pip. For example, to get the GTK3 wxPython builds for Ubuntu 18.04 (and 16.10, LinuxMint 18, and probably others) you can use a pip command like this:

pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-18.04 \
    wxPython

Of course you can always download the wheel file yourself and then use pip to install your local copy of the file.

Comment: In the end, this was the only solution which worked for me. Lubuntu 18.04 users, I grabbed `wxPython-4.0.6-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` using `wget`, then installed (very fast!) with `sudo pip3 install wxPython-4.0.6-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`.

Answer (score 2):

First I found it by:

```
sudo apt search python3-wx
```

I installed the latest wxpython with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-wxgtk4.0 python3-wxgtk-webview4.0 python3-wxgtk-media4.0
```

You may also try synaptic to install it that way if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

if any one revised this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
```

try this

```
sudo apt install make gcc libgtk-3-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev python-gst-1.0 python3-gst-1.0 libglib2.0-dev ubuntu-restricted-extras libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0
```